# How do I fill color space in a CGrect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using the code below and am trying everything to color the resulting circle that it draws, but cannot for the life of me figure it out! Can anyone help? How do I color the circle in that my method draws?

What I have so far is this:

```
-(void)drawCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint)p withRadius:(CGFloat)radius inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddArc(context, p.x, p.y, radius, 0, 2*M_PI, YES);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext(); 
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGPoint midPoint;
    midPoint.x = self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width/2;
    midPoint.y = self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.width/2;

    CGFloat size = self.bounds.size.width/2;
    if (self.bounds.size.height < self.bounds.size.width) size = self.bounds.size.height/2;
    size *= 0.90;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];

    CGColorRef color = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    [self drawCircleAtPoint:midPoint withRadius:size inContext:context];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to fill the current path, but you haven't added anything to it yet. The only point at which you add anything to the current path is in `drawCircleAtPoint:withRadius:inContext:`, after which you only stroke it.

Move your `CGContextFillPath` call into that method. You'll want to fill before you stroke, since the stroke will reset the current path. (If you want to fill on top of the inside of the stroke, you'll need to save the gstate before stroking and restore it after, so that the current path is still set when you fill.)